# Where can I find the most popular Solana programs?

Tags: solana-program

I am doing a small research on blockchains and I want to analyze the most popular Solana programs (ideally, most popular entry points). Where can I find addresses so that I can download the bytecode?

So far I have tried https://analytics.solscan.io/overview but it does not allow me to rank programs based on number of times they were executed.

Any help or pointers are appreciated!